# Pintar célula com formatação condicional utilizando SE

Tags: microsoft-excel

Queria saber como faço para pintar a celular de um determinado valor:

Por exemplo: Tenho o salário de R$100,00 na célula A1
Na célula  B2 vai a somatória das minhas contas
Então na célula C1 gostaria pintar de vermelho se as contas passassem de R$100,00 e de verde se não passase.

[image: Formatação Condicional]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a opção de formatação condicional:

[image: Passo1]

[image: Passo2]

[image: Passo3]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para pintar de verde utilize outra formatação condicionar com o "Maior Que" e peça para pintar de verde.

Comment: Rodolpho entendi o que você quis dizer. Mas eu precisa isso tudo na mesma célula. Vou editar a minha pergunta e colocar o a imagem de exemplo lá

Comment: Editado, coloquei a imagem para melhor entendimento.

Comment: @Arthur Você pode usar duas formatações condicionais na mesma célula. Uma "É Maior do que..." e outra "É Menor do que..." sendo que uma vai pintar de verde  e outra de vermelho.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Não sabia disso. Pensei que uma subscrevia a outra. Fechou então. Já fiz aqui e deu certo. Obrigado cara.